# How to capture Liferay Logged In User details in JSP (Say email-ID , name etc)

Tags: jsp, liferay

I want to capture Liferay Logged In User details in JSP (Say email-ID , name etc). I dont want to use any framework. I am new to JAVA and Liferay so any detailed step will be a great help for me to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add to your jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme"%>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
```

than you can just use

```
<%= user.getEmailAddress() %>
```

or if you use jstl than

```
${user.emailAddress}
```

meaning `<liferay-theme:defineObjects />` has put user object in page context.

Look up `com.liferay.portal.model.User` to see all properties available.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply. I have added the above mentioned snippets but I am getting "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page" error. Any specific suggestion how I can use your code?

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme"%>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />                                                       <%= user.getEmailAddress() %>                                          I have added only the lines mentioned by you. Let me know if I am missing something as I am new to Liferay and JAVA. Thanks

Comment: I meant whole jsp. Do you have your own portlet or modify some existing jsp if so which.

Comment: My jsp page only contains your code I have not added anything else. To simplify my requirement say I just want to display "Hello <Logged-in-user> " that's it.

Comment: Ok. How are you using that jsp? Did you write a portlet that is using that jsp? Or?

Comment: Its just a iframe that is calling JSP file.

Comment: My requirement is how I can fetch Liferay current logged-in user's email-ID in a seperate JSP file (not portlet, simple JSP file). If possible let me know. Thanks

Comment: @SunilRai First Martin is assuming is assuming that you are working with a portlet and you need user id in your portlet's jsp. If it is not the case, you need to explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Sandeep I think now my requirement is clear that in a separate JSP page how can I fetch logged-in user email ID. I hope my requirement is clear now otherwise let me know if you need any clarification. Any guidance in this regard will be great for me. Thanks

Comment: @Sunil With the setup that you mention you're leaving the portal world - and you don't get the portal context over to this world easily. You're basically back at a servlet application where you can't rely on the infrastructure of the portal - in fact, you can rely on the infrastructure not being there. If you don't need the portal environment: Don't use it. If you need it: Accept that it's there and stay in the portal/portlet, don't go for iframe. Martin's code works if you use it in a portlet.

Comment: ok I will check the portlet development and try to implement this. Thanks for your elaboration.

Comment: Thanks for all the support. I have created new portlet and the above mentioned code by Martin is working. Thanks again Martin :)

Answer (score 3):

In any of your login jsp pages, you can get the user object of the one who logged in by calling the method:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
User objUser=themeDisplay.getUser();
```

From this objUser, you can get all the details you need.

Comment: If you want to just display the name, you can do it using  http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10832920

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the user information in a JSP using the following:

```
long uid = com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getUserId(request);

User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserById(uid);
```